# How to use querySelector with an anchor tag with href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use dropzone and I have a anchor tag and I need to add a event click to it but the way I'm done this returns error.

Html:

```
<a href="#new-intervention">Criar Intervenção</a>
```

Jquery:

```
var myDropzone = this;

this.element.querySelector("a[href=#new-intervention]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  myDropzone.processQueue();
 });
```

And return me this in console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'a[href=#new-intervention]' is not a valid selector.
```

How can I do that? What is the alternative?

Comment: Wrap the href value in single quotes ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message already gives it away. The selector should be `a[href='#new-intervention']`. Notice the single quotes around the value of `href`.

Here is a simplified snippet to show the selector working:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("a[href='#new-intervention']"));
```

```html
<a href="#new-intervention">Criar Intervenção</a>
```

Note that [according to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), the value provided must either be a valid [identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) or a [string](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

Comment: I want o do this because of this situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230811/laravel-and-dropzone-how-to-get-files-in-server-side#48231358 . I appreciate If you can help me with that. @NisargShah

Comment: @user3242861 I don't understand laravel. Do you mean you can't wrap that value in single quotes in the selector?

Comment: No, you solutions works fine! I just try to explain the reason that I need that and to solve that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You just the missed the quotes `'` inside the href value query selector expression ;

see below snippet :

```js
document.querySelector("a[href='#new-intervention']").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert("a clicked");
 });
```

```html
<a href="#new-intervention">Criar Intervenção</a>
```